# Python convert list of str to list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with data in the following format:

```
['[10,2,3,4]','[5,26,17,28]','[10,13,36,48]']
```

How do I convert this to:

```
[[10,2,3,4],[5,26,17,28],[10,13,36,48]] ?
```

Which I think would be converting a list of str to a list of lists of int.
I have tried using all suggested methods such as list comprehensions, map etc, but either end up with each individual integer as a str e.g. 48 as '4','8',... or stays exactly the same. I am using Python 3.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string representation of list to list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to evaluate those strings to actual lists.

```
>>> import ast
>>> lst = ['[10,2,3,4]','[5,26,17,28]','[10,13,36,48]']
>>> [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in lst]
[[10, 2, 3, 4], [5, 26, 17, 28], [10, 13, 36, 48]]
```

This is similar to `eval`uating the lists, except that `literal_eval`, as the name suggests, will only evaluate Python literals, which makes it much safer than the builtin `eval`.